# Is it possible to create a reuseable fetch function in React Native?

Tags: node.js, react-native

I'm new in React native.

I need to create a reusable fetch function.

So i will explain what i need :

1. I need to fetch Token first
2. I will request other API after get the token
3. Activity number 1 will execute everytime i execute an API.

Here my code :

```
fetch('https://myapi.myurl.com/getToken')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
   //First API -- Always need to request it to get Token
   fetch('https://myapi.myurl.com/doCheck')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {

        //My Second API - this API can be change according to case

     });


    });
```

> Is it possible to create function that can change second API without
>   re-coding first API calling ? How to achieve that ?

Thank you.

Comment: Create a function and paste the fetch inside it and make it dynamic with params

Comment: Can you give example?

Comment: why you need to fetch token everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this..

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: '',
      token: '',
      flag: 1
    };

    this.fetchData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1');
    this.fetchData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2');
  }

  async fetchData(url) {
    await fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        if (this.state.flag) {
          this.setState({ token: responseJson, flag: 0 });
        } else {
          this.setState({ data: responseJson });
        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    const lol = JSON.stringify(data);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>API test</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.token.name}</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.data.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Now you have DRY code.

Check the live [demo here](https://snack.expo.io/@raajnadar/api-dry-code)

Comment: your second line of code in last block doesn't wait for first, or Is it work another way?

Comment: @Adrian fixed the issue now both the fetched data can be displayed on the screen

Answer (score 0):

I mean no offence, but Naaj's code won't work because the fetch is a promise.

It sounds like you need to create a simple function.

You are working with promises, so I will rewrite for better promise-flow, and hopefully easier to understand;

I would have done something like this;

```
// You might need a parameter here, but I don't know the details of your API.
function doCheckSomething(myParameter) {
  return fetch('https://myapi.myurl.com/getToken')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    // Return the other promise here, so it will actually resolve on the entire method
    return fetch('https://myapi.myurl.com/doCheck')
  })
  .then((response) => response.json()) // Moved down for de-nesting. Because we have promises all the way, we can do this.
}
```

Then, you would use this method like this:

```
doCheckSomething("whatever")
.then(resultingJson => {
  // Do whatever you need with the /doCheck data.
})
.catch(console.error) // Print errors, in case there are any.
```

You might have to actually re-write this a little bit to inject the required data where you need it. Like the first `responseJson` into the second api-check.

Comment: How i can change fetch('https://myapi.myurl.com/doCheck') ? getToken always call, but fetch('https://myapi.myurl.com/doCheck') is flexible according to case.

Comment: You can write something like `if(responseJson.whatever){return fetch('https://myapi.com/doCheck')} else {return Promise.resolve()}` in stead of `return fetch...`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function to wrap your request with the `getToken` :

```
function myCustomFetch(url, params) {
  return fetch('https://myapi.myurl.com/getToken')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((responseToken) => {
      // First API -- Always need to request it to get Token
      return fetch(url, {
        ...params,
        headers: { Authorization: responseToken.token },
      }).then(response => response.json());
    });
}
```

(Please note I'm using object destructuring/spread in order to pass `headers` param)

Then use it like this (to make a post request for example) :

```
myCustomFetch('https://myapi.myurl.com/doCheck', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: myBodyPayload,
}).then((response) => {
  // do something with response
});
```